# How to avoid to blow up transaction log?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table which stores data out of a complex query. This table is truncated and new populated once per hour. As you might assume this is for performance reason so the application accesses this table and not the query.

Is truncate and insert the only way to resolve this task cheap, or are there other possibilities in respect of the transaction log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am assuming right, you are using this table as a temp table to store some records and want to remove all records from this table every one hour, right?

Truncate is always minimally logged. So yes, truncate and then insert will work. Another option is to create a new table with same structure. Drop old table and then rename new table to the old table name.

If you want to avoid the above, you can explore the "simple" recovery model (this has implications on point of time recovery - so be very careful with this if you have other tables in this same database). Or you can create a new database which will just have this one table, set recovery for this DB to "simple". Simple recovery model will help you keep your t-log small.

Lastly, if you have  to have full recovery and also cannot use "truncate" or "drop" options from above, you should at the very least backup your t-log at very regular intervals (depending on how big its growing and how much space you have).

Comment: +1 If the table is not shared with other users then you might get some performance benefits by using #temp.  I think you can drop a #temp even if logging is not simple.  Since you are holding the results for up to an hour it appears that you can accept stale reads so use with (nolock) hint in you query.

Comment: "Truncate is always minimally logged. So yes, truncate and then insert will work." Is it the INSERT-Statement that fills the log?
And why should the create table in form of "select * into hourely_table from source_table" not fill the log?

Comment: depends how you are doing the inserts. Normally, inserts are fully logged. Certain bulk-insert operations are minimally logged. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244.aspx for list of operations that can be minimally logged and under what circumstances.